# How can I make an bs4Dash accordion item be expanded on startup in r shiny?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, bs4dash

Is it possible to have a bs4Dash accordion item to be expanded on startup? In my knowledge the accordion function doesn’t have an input value so I guess that you have to use some javascript instead, but my javascript knowledge isn't very good.

Here is is some example code with a failed javascript try:

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)

shiny::shinyApp(
  ui = bs4DashPage(
    navbar = bs4DashNavbar(),
    sidebar = bs4DashSidebar(),
    controlbar = bs4DashControlbar(),
    footer = bs4DashFooter(),
    title = "test",
    body = bs4DashBody(
      bs4Accordion(
        id = "accordion",
        bs4AccordionItem(
          id = "item1",
          title = "Item 1",
          status = "danger",
          "Some text here"
        ),
        bs4AccordionItem(
          id = "item2",
          title = "Item 2",
          status = "warning",
          "Some text here"
        )
      ),
      tags$head(tags$script('
        $(document).on("shiny:sessioninitialized", function(event) {
          document.querySelector("#header_item1 a").setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
        });
      '))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `shiny:sessioninitialized` event is being triggered (use devtools to check for events). Do you get any errors in your console log?

Comment: If I change the second row in the javascript to "alert("hello")", I get the popup so i guess it's being triggered

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is new since you posted the question, but there is an argument called 'collapsed' that can be set to FALSE. If you do this, the accordion item will be open upon Shiny app launch.

```
accordionItem(
title = "Foo",
collapsed = F
...
)
```